# addEventListner in a for loop

Tags: javascript, dom

```
myDiv = document.getElementById('results');

div = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');


for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var division;
    division = div[i];

    // console.log(div[i]);

    division.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        division.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        division.style.background = "rgba(0, 7, 255, 0.29)";
    }, false);

    division.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        division.style.fontWeight = "";
        division.style.background = "";

    }, false);
```

Here is the html code :

```
<div id="results">
    <div>Resulat 1</div>
    <div>Resulat 2</div>

</div>
```

My script which bold and put a background on some text is when the mouse pointer is over it working only for the second element.. (    `<div>Resulat 2</div>`)

Can someone tell me why because everything I did is right for me, even though I'm a JS beginner.

Comment: Instead of doing it in a loop please considering adding it to some container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `division` in your `function()`? It is the same as the `division` you change in every iteration at `division = div[i];`. After your for-loop has finished `division` is `div[1]`. This is why you only change the second div.

You could use a closure to tackle this problem, or use access the associated object with `this`:

```
division.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    this.style.background = "rgba(0, 7, 255, 0.29)";
}, false);

division.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    this.style.fontWeight = "";
    this.style.background = "";
}, false);
```

However, your desired effect can be easily achieved with CSS:

```css
#results > div:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:rgba(0,7,255,0.29);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see.. thank you, +1 I'll accept your answer. Thanks too for the suggestion with CSS, I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

use `this`:

```
division.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    this.style.background = "rgba(0, 7, 255, 0.29)";
}, false);

division.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.style.fontWeight = "";
    this.style.background = "";    
}, false);​
```

`division` will hold the last div because of the loop.
[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRrm9/1/)

---

Another way if necessary is to create a private scope- closure for each iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    (function() {
        var division = div[i];;

        division.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            division.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            division.style.background = "rgba(0, 7, 255, 0.29)";
        }, false);

        division.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            division.style.fontWeight = "";
            division.style.background = "";

        }, false);
    })();
}​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRrm9/)

Comment: @Meds, you welcome, I added a second part about closure, though It's not necessary here, you wrote you want to learn js, this is a good scenario to learn about closures.

Comment: @Meds. Added demos, I hope it will help you understand clousers.

Comment: Realy nice, good to know, I'll learn more about those closures, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the last element that "division" is set to w/ the event listeners. To do as you wish, use "this" in it's place:

```
myDiv = document.getElementById('results');

div = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var division = div[i];

    division.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        this.style.background = "rgba(0, 7, 255, 0.29)";
    }, false);

    division.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        this.style.background = "inherit";
    }, false);
}
```